# Windows 7 says I've got 3 monitors but I've only got 2

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have recently added a second monitor to a friends computer and it is working fine, except that it says that I have got three screens and the main screen it says is two.

The below screenshot will clarify more:

[image]

The problem is that when I go into a game (or other fullscreen programs) it will change the order of the screens, so screen #1 will be on the left after I come out of a game.

Please let me know if you can think of anyway of changing/stopping this.

Comment: Just set 2/3 to be a single display.

Comment: Sorry, may be being a bit dim, but how do you do that?

Comment: Drop down box next to `Display:`

Comment: Sorry yeah done that :) Thanks mate, it worked. If you want to submit it as an answer then I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot you currently have "2|3. Multiple Monitors" on the display setting.

Click on the drop down and set it to be a single display.